# python manage.py runserver Vs foreman start for custom User model

Tags: python, django, foreman, django-custom-user

I have an app that uses `django_mongodb_engine` and `mongolab`(no python manage.py syncdb required). I also am using `foreman` as my local server.

Procfile:

`web: gunicorn <appname>.wsgi`

I have the the following custom user model called `Registration`:

```
class Registration(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    zone = models.IntegerField()

    objects = RegistrationManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['created_at', 'zone']
```

Now when I type in `foreman start`, it works exactly how I wanted it to be. That is `USERNAME_FIELD` as `not unique`, but when I try it with `python manage.py runserver`, while validating models it gives me the following error:

```
CommandError: The USERNAME_FIELD must be unique. Add unique=True to the field parameters.
```

When I deploy it on Heroku it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD)

`USERNAME_FIELD` must be defined as Unique=True

Comment: but it also works if you dont with foreman or gunicorn rather